# Laravel Photo Upload using LaravelCollective

Tags: laravel

When I try to submit the form an Error occurs.

```
public function store(){
        $story = new Story;  
        $story->file_link  = $request->resume_link;
        $story->save();

        $fileName = $story->id . '.' .
        $request->file('file_link')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $requests->file('file_link')->move(
            base_path() . '/public/uploads', $fileName  
            );

        $story->file_link  = $fileName;

        return redirect('home');
    }
```

What this does is mainly to store the file i uploaded. Please upvote this post. I am banned due to this question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To be more precise, Laravel Collective is really a collection of packages that are removed from Laravel core. I am assuming you are talking about the HTML/Forms package. To answer your question, I think the docs are self-explanatory enough.

To generate a file input (front end)

```
{{ Form::file('image') }}
```

To "retrieve" the file (back end controller)

```
$file = $request->file('image');
```

You need to be more precise on your question. What are you confused about?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might solve your problem.
Your blade template code will be

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="image">Chose the picture</label>
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image" {{ $errors->has('image') ? 'class=has-error' : '' }} value="{{ $photo->image }}">
  </div>
```

Your Controller code will be

```
$logo=$request->file('image');
$upload='uploads/logo';
$filename=$logo->getClientOriginalName();
$success=$logo->move($upload,$filename);
$doctor->image = $filename;
```